# Cocoa performClick: in awakeFromNib not working

Tags: cocoa, nib, sender

Im trying to call `performClick:` from `awakeFromNib` and its not working. I think its because it needs a sender and `awakeFromNib` has no sender. I have tried using `nil`,`self` and `sender` as the sender of `performClick:` but none seem to work. My code is

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
[myButton performClick:sender];
}
```

Can anyone think of a work around for this? Thanks for any help

Comment: How do you know that `performClick:` is not working?  Have you hooked up an action method to the button and verified that the method is not getting called?  Are there any clues in the console log when the code runs?

Comment: It's very rare that you need to use `performClick:` instead of sending a message yourself. What are you trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: I want to use performClick: to click a button to stop a QCView until its stated later. I'm almost positive it is impossible to call stop: on a QCView via cocoa.

Comment: Have you actually *tried* calling `stop:` or `stopRendering`?

Comment: Yes, stopRending is not working and stop: according to the documentation is ib only.

Comment: I just tried [qcview isRendering] and it returns NO, even though I still see it running...

Answer (score 1):

You should always call `[super awakeFromNib]` because you never know what the super class is doing.

`awakeFromNib` is a bad place to put `performClick:` because although everything is loaded and initialized, there is no guarantee everything has been enabled and is visible. If a button is disabled or hidden, it will ignore the `performClick` message.

Comment: Okay im stuck because I need to call stop: on a qcview but this can only be done from ib?

Comment: happyCoding25: No, calling `stop:` cannot only be done from IB, partly because IB does not call the action methods you hook up in it. Any method that's listed in the documentation http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzFramework/Classes/QCView_Class/ , you can call.

Comment: Thanks I've tried using stopRendering before but it continues to run.

Comment: You should call the super implementation of awakeFromNib only if you know for certain that your superclass provides an implementation. Because the Application Kit does not provide a default implementation of the awakeFromNib method, calling super results in an exception if the parent class does not implement it. Classes whose immediate parent class is NSObject or NSView do not need to call the super implementation. For any other classes, you can use the instancesRespondToSelector: class method of NSObject to determine if the parent class responds to awakeFromNib and call the method if it does.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't hooked up your `qcview` outlet. Everything you've said is consistent with sending a message to `nil`, which does nothing and returns `nil`, `Nil`, `NULL`, `NO`, `0`, or `0.0`.

Comment: Then maybe you haven't loaded your nib. You can test both things at once by logging the pointer in the `qcview` outlet: `NSLog(@"qcview: %p", qcview);`